# Show the map is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha$ be integral, $f=\min(\alpha,\mathbb{Q})$, and $a,p\in \mathbb{Z}$ be such that $p$ is prime and $f(a)\equiv 0\mod p$. I would like to show that the map
$$\phi: \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\to \mathbb{Z}/p$$
given by $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ and $\alpha\mapsto \bar{a}$ is a ring homomorphism.

**My attempt**: Let $d=\deg(f)$. I do know $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ and that each element of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ can be uniquely written as
$$\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}z_i\alpha^i$$
for some $z_i\in \mathbb{Z}$. Using this fact makes it very easy to show $\phi$ respects addition. I am having trouble showing it respects multiplication. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The map $\psi:\Bbb{Z}[x]\to\Bbb{Z}$ gotten by evaluation polynomials at $a$ is always a homomorphism of rings (you only need commutativity of $\Bbb{Z}$ for this to hold). Therefore so is the composition $\overline{\psi}$ of $\psi$ followed by reduction modulo $p$. It follows that $f(x)\in\mathrm{Ker}(\overline{\psi})$, and therefore $\overline{\psi}$ induces a well defined homomorphism from the quotient ring.

Comment: To clarify you mean $f(x)\in \text{Ker}(\bar{\psi}\circ\psi)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the ring structure stays preserved under quotients by ideals, you know that this map preserves the ring structure, so it is sufficient to show that it is well defined. If you do not know this, you need to prove this.

If you are allowed to use the isomorphism in your attempt, then we can define this isomorphism as the map
$$
\psi : \Bbb Z[x]/(f(x)) \to \Bbb Z[\alpha],\; x \mapsto \alpha.
$$
Then 
$$
\phi \circ \psi : \Bbb Z[x]/(f(x)) \to \Bbb Z/(p),\; x \mapsto \bar a
$$
This is the map that evaluates a polynomial $g \in \Bbb Z[x]/(f(x))$ at $x = \bar a$. Now it is clear that if this polynomial $g$ is inside the ideal $(f(x))$ then $f(x)$ divides it, so $g(\bar a) \equiv 0 \mod p$. So $(f(x)) \subset \ker \phi \circ \psi$, which shows the map is well defined.

Comment: Could you explain how $\phi\circ\psi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism? I think it is due to the universal property of polynomial rings, but not sure if $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$ meets this criteria. Also, the kernel would be $\langle p,x-a\rangle$ correct?

Comment: @northcity4 $\psi$ is an isomorphism, so you only need to check $\phi$.

Comment: That makes sense. My concern was showing $\phi$ respects multiplication, but with the division algorithm (division by $f(x)$) I think I got it. Thank you again.